# Approximation of harmonious numbers

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, roots, approximation

I have a question about an approximation of so-called "harmonious numbers". These are a generalisation of the golden ratio, the plastic number, and so on, (related to the Fibonacci and Padovan sequences respectively). Their decimal expansions to $5\ sf$ for illustration:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n& 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\ \hline
χ_n & 1.6180 & 1.3247 & 1.2207 & 1.1673 & 1.1347 & 1.1128 & 1.0970 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Studied by Dutch architect Dom Hans van der Laan in the 1920s, they are basically the positive real solutions to the equations

\begin{align}
&x^n = x+1 \quad \quad \ (n\geq 2, \ n\in\mathbb{Z})\\
\end{align}

They appear to be quite nicely approximated by

\begin{align}
&\frac{2 n - 1 + \log 2}{2 n - 1 - \log 2}\\
\end{align}

I was just wondering whether anyone could shed some light on why this might be the case?

*ref*:
[**Plastic number: construction and applications**
*L Marohnić, T Strmečki*](https://bib.irb.hr/datoteka/628836.Plastic_Number_-_Construct.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we consider the equation $$x^n = x+1$$ it means that we look for the inverse of
$$n=\frac{\log (x+1)}{\log (x)}$$ Building the $[1,1]$ Padé approximant of the rhs around $x=1$, we have
$$n=\frac{\log (2)+\frac{1}{2} (1+\log (2))(x-1) }{x-1 } $$ Solving for $x$ gives
$$\color{red}{x_1=\frac{2 n - 1 + \log (2)}{2 n - 1 - \log (2)}}$$ which is the formula.

We could do better  building the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant of the rhs around $x=1$ and obtain
$$\color{red}{x_2=\frac{2 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{12n^2-12n+(4 \log ^2(2)-6 \log (2)+3 ) } +(8 \log (2)-3)}{12 n-(9+4 \log (2)) }}$$
Comparing the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & x_1 & x_2 & \text{solution} \\
 2 & 1.6009462 & 1.6179521 &  1.6180340 \\
 3 & 1.3218811 & 1.3247134 &  1.3247180 \\
 4 & 1.2198076 & 1.2207433 &  1.2207441 \\
 5 & 1.1668856 & 1.1673038 &  1.1673040 \\
 6 & 1.1345022 & 1.1347241 &  1.1347243 \\
 7 & 1.1126441 & 1.1127757 &  1.1127757 \\
 8 & 1.0968972 & 1.0969815 &  1.0969816 \\
 9 & 1.0850130 & 1.0850702 &  1.0850703 \\
 10 & 1.0757254 & 1.0757661 &  1.0757661 \\
 11 & 1.0682673 & 1.0682972 &  1.0682972 \\
 12 & 1.0621466 & 1.0621692 &  1.0621692 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

You can have still better writing
$$\color{red}{x_3=x_1-\frac{x_1 (x_1+1) (n \log (x_1)-\log (x_1+1))}{x_1 (n-1)+n}}$$

Now, may be the simplest
$$x=1+t+(2n-1)\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{P_k(n)}{ 2^{k-1}\,k!}u^k $$
$$t=\frac{2\log(2)}{2n-1} \qquad \qquad u=\frac t{2n-1}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & P_k(n) \\
 2 & 4 n-1 \\
 3 & 16 n^2-4 n+1 \\
 4 & 64 n^3-8 n^2+20 n-1 \\
 5 & 256 n^4-32 n^3+264 n^2+52 n+1 \\
 6 & 1024 n^5-384 n^4+1568 n^3+1984 n^2+492 n-1 \\
 7 & 4096 n^6-1536 n^5-2112 n^4+17984 n^3+24672 n^2+4188 n+1\\ 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using the above terms, the goden ratio is reproduced within an absolute error of $6.21\times 10^{-7}$ and the plastic number  within an absolute error of $3.12\times 10^{-9}$.

**Update**

There is another way to generate approximation considering
$$f(x)=n\,\log(x)-\log(x+1)$$
Let
$$x_{(k)}=\frac{\sum _{i=0}^k a_i\, n^i } {\sum _{i=0}^k b_i\, n^i  }$$ and expand $f(x_{(k)})$ as a series for infinitely large values of $n$. This gives for example
$$\color{blue}{x_{(2)}=\frac{24 n^2+12 (\lambda -2) n+\left(2 \lambda ^2-9 \lambda
   +6\right) }{24 n^2-12 (\lambda +2) n+\left(2 \lambda ^2+3 \lambda
   +6\right) }}\qquad (\lambda=\log(2))$$

Comment: Amazing! Thanks you for introducing me to a new concept!

Comment: @martin. There is nothing very special here beside function approximation. Cheers :-)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit on you last comment? Are you applying something like a Newton method in defining $x_3$?

Comment: @Giafazio. Exactly ! This is the first iterate of Newton method for $f(x)=n\log(x)-\log(x+1)$ starting at $x_1$. Good catch

Comment: Wow, looks like some progress! Have just seen update, so will have to take a little time to digest though..

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are only two morphic numbers. From this reference:  [Jan Aarts, Robbert Fokkink, Godfried Kruijtzer, Morphic numbers, NAW 5/2 nr. 2 maart 2001](http://www.nieuwarchief.nl/serie5/pdf/naw5-2001-02-1-056.pdf), we have the definition

A real number $p$ > 1 is called a morphic number if
there exist natural numbers $k$ and $l$ such that
$$p + 1 = p^k \text{ and } \ p − 1 = p^{−l}$$ The only two numbers that satisfy this condition are the golden ratio and the plastic number.

You may be thinking of the [Metallic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_mean), which are given by

$$m = \frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+4}}{2}, \quad n\ge 0$$

EDIT: The OP has pointed out that he meant the *harmonious* numbers. I'm familiar with these as well. They derive from the equation $X+1=X^m$, for $m>1$. In addition, they arise from the sequence

$$f_k=f_{k-m+1}+f_{k-m},\quad k<m\\
f_{k\le1}=1\\
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{f_{k+1}}{f_k}=X
$$

These constitute for about half of what I call the *pseudomorphic* numbers, the remainder of which are defined by $\chi-1=\chi^{-n}, n>1$, or

$$f_k=f_{k-1}+f_{k-1-n},\quad k>n+1\\
f_{k\le n+1}=1\\
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{f_{k+1}}{f_k}=\chi
$$

Comment: yes, you are right, bt I didn't mean metallic mean. Please see update.

Comment: nice. Any idea on how to get the approximation / expansion?

Comment: Sorry, I've moved recently and don't have all my reference material handy. You might get some insight from the OEIS A103372 and related (at oeis.org)

Comment: yes, I did look there. Thanks anyway!